# df.mean is not the real mean of the Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm debugging and run into the following strange behavior.
I'm calculating the mean of a pandas series which contains all exactly the same numbers. However, the `pd.mean()` gives a different number.

question1: why mean of this Series is a different number?

question2: `tmm[-1]== tmm.mean()` gives `False` now. Any way to ignore this small difference and make the results True? I don't prefer `abs(tmm[-1]-tmm.mean()) < xxx`

methods because not sure how to define `xxx`.

```
import pandas as pd
import decimal

tmm = pd.Series(14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
                index=range(30))
for t in tmm:
    print(decimal.Decimal(t))
print('mean is')
print(decimal.Decimal(tmm.mean()))
```

results:

```
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
mean is
14.9200000000000034816594052244909107685089111328125
```

Comment: `float`s are intrinsically prone to precision errors, that's why you get a different mean.

Comment: "I don't prefer `abs(tmm[-1]-tmm.mean()) < xxx`".  Well, bummer then.  You can't rely on float values being exactly equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [np.isclose()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

```
tmm[20]== tmm.mean()

False

np.isclose(tmm[20], tmm.mean())
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your 2 questions is basically this:

```
import pandas as pd
import decimal

tmm = pd.Series(decimal.Decimal(14.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875),
                index=range(30))
for t in tmm:
    print(decimal.Decimal(t))
print('mean is')
print(decimal.Decimal(tmm.mean()))
```

Make sure you use decimal.Decimal constructor when you're creating tmm, that's pretty much.